# Android: Best method for creating buttons in non-standard UI? ie: yes or no screen with custom background and options

Tags: android, button

I've been wondering this for a while. What's the best method to create custom buttons? Currently I have an image, it contains a background with a yes and no. Should I have my artists create the image with the words yes and no separate, or is there a way to create buttons on top of this background? Perhaps make the buttons transparent? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) class with a custom background drawable and desired text styling. The background drawable should be a [state list selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). This will allow you to define a separate [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) for each state - pressed, enabled, disabled, focused, etc. The text itself will be drawn by the system on top of the button, allowing you to use localized string resources to support multiple languages.